# Управление LPT портом в NodeJS

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, драйвер, lpt

Как можно из-под Linux (debian) управлять вводом-выводом через LPT порт используя NodeJS?

Требования просты - включить/выключить светодиод через D0-D7, читать состояние вкл/выкл переключателя из ACK/BUSY.

Сделал подобное на C, написал примитивный скрипт используя `ioperm` и outb (sys/io.h), работает. Можно ли написать подобное в NodeJS, попробовать написать нативный модуль?

Есть пакет [node-lpt](https://github.com/shemanaev/node-lpt)
но у меня он не работает, в доке написано что нужен `parport` драйвер скомпиленный для Linux.

Может кто-нибудь подсказать как лучше сделать это?

Comment: Ну, а в чём проблема сказать `modprobe parport`?

Comment: Оказалось все гораздо проще, порт упоминался в файлах `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` и `/etc/modules-load.d/cups-filters.conf` как `lp parport parport_pc ppdev`. После удаления соответствующих записей пакет node-lpt прекрасно работает. Спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первым делом убедитесь что порт включен в настройках BIOS, а также проверьте нету ли в системе ограничений использования lpt порта.